# Map followers/following relationship with Restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

In my core data project I have a `User` entity with a `followers`/`following` relationship which destination is also the `User` entity.

To get the info of a given `user` I call an endpoint with this structure: `user/:id/`
To fetch his `followers`/`following` users I call: `/user/:id/followers`

I have added the following routes to the `RKObjectManager`:

```
[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithRelationshipName:@"followers" objectClass:[User class] pathPattern:@"user/:id/followers" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithRelationshipName:@"following" objectClass:[User class] pathPattern:@"user/:id/following" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
```

Then I call:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:@"followers" ofObject:user parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    
}];
```

But RestKit cannot perform the mapping. I guess I'm missing adding to relationship information to the `RKEntityMapping` of the `User` entity. I've tried different approached but none successful. I appreciate any help on this issue.

#### Update

Here is the User entity mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id":                 @"id",
     @"name":               @"name",
     @"user_name":          @"username"}];
```

And the descriptior:

```
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                  method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                             pathPattern:@"user/:id/followers"
                                                 keyPath:nil
                      statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]
```

I guess I should add something to the `userMapping` referencing followers/following but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show the mapping and response descriptor definitions. Also turn on mapping trace logging and see what it tells you.

Comment: Are the `User` objects for the relationship created and mapped but not connected, or are they not created and mapped at all?

Comment: When I do 'getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:@"followers"'? They are created and mapped, but not connected.

Comment: Hi :) Have you found a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a limitation / bug in RestKit. You may want to raise this on the issues list in RestKit github page.

Your simplest fix should be to connect the relationship in the success block using the items provided in the `mappingResult` and the source `user` object.